# Is there something like monitor for deferreds (Q) in node.js?

Tags: node.js, logging, monitoring, deferred, q

I want see all the unresolved states (if possible all the log of deferreds: init, unresolved, resolved/rejected states). Is there any mechanism for it?

Something like: `Q.getAllDeferreds()`, or `Q.getLog()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deferred implementation (I'm the author) offers things like unresolved promises monitor and promise "usage statistics", check https://github.com/medikoo/deferred#monitoring-unresolved-promises

Comment: do you maybe know, how to use this functionality in the Q module?

Comment: @static internals are very different, so it's not pluggable I'm afraid. You may use Deferred instead (which doesn't lack anything when comparing to Q, I'd say it's rather opposite), or just post a issue on Q project page requesting same functionality.

Comment: ok, I implemented now "my own monitor" (unfortunately without blackjack and hookers :) only as an array with a pair of methods for filtering resolved/rejected/pending promises and decorating the console output. I will take look on Deffered in the nearest future (it is not the main part of the application now)

Comment: Sure, what plays best for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "q" ...

See the "Progress Notification" section and the bit about "deferred.notify" in the "Using Deferreds" section - [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

But please note that it says (as one might expect) "not all promises will implement progress notifications", so unless your worker module provides for notifications, then there's nothing you can do about it on the promise-consuming side. You can set up a progress handler in a `.then()`, but it will not fire unless the module calls `deferred.notify()`.

Of course, if the worker module is of your own construction (or otherwise under your control) then you can modify it to provide notifications.